# CORS preflight request error not solved by installing npm cors package

Tags: javascript, npm, cors

After getting below console error (from use of `fetch api`),

**Console Error:**

> Fetch API cannot load https://... Response to preflight request
>   doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
>   header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://...' is
>   therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.
>   If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to
>   'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I attempted solve the issue by installing the `npm cors package`.

```
npm install cors --save
```

Then added to server.js

```
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
```

**Cors package setup instructions**:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

But I'm still getting the same preflight request error. Can anyone advise if additional setup for cors package is required, or if something else might need to be done?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#enabling-cors-pre-flight

look at that, since your browser is considering it as a "complex" request

Comment: Per that documentation i also tried, `app.options('/quotes', cors());` and `app.put('/quotes', cors(), (req, res)...` (placing `cors()` directly into the request), But it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the server is not adding "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" or the header value has wrong domain. Try sending "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header with value * and see if it works.

You can see more here https://dariuscoder.com/2021/09/16/how-to-debug-cors/

Since you say it is 404 code, so maybe your application/framework you use does not add the header in case it did not find some resource.